# Get Bidirectional Unicode Character Type in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, localization

See the first 2 rows of [bidirectional character types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-directional_text#Table_of_possible_BiDi-types). How, in Objective-C, can I tell if a character is in the scope of left-to-right (1st row) or right-to-left (second row)?